# 3D perspective view in iphone game using cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing '`Paper Toss'` for iphone using `cocos2d` & I would like to know that how to implement `3D` perspective view into this,because while we are throwing the paper ball to the bin,we have to get the `3D` feel.I'am attaching the code which i have done,using this i have got a straight line motion.Please help me..

```
*- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

// Choose one of the touches to work with
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

// Set up initial location of projectile
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
CCSprite *projectile = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ball.png" 
                                           rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
projectile.position = ccp(winSize.width/2,20);

// Determine offset of location to projectile
int offX = location.x - projectile.position.x;
int offY = location.y - projectile.position.y;

// Bail out if we are shooting down or backwards
if (offY <= 0) return;

// Ok to add now - we've double checked position
[self addChild:projectile];

// Determine where we wish to shoot the projectile to
int realY = winSize.height + (projectile.contentSize.width/2);
float ratio = (float) offX / (float) offY;
int realX = (realY * ratio) + projectile.position.x;
CGPoint realDest = ccp(realX, realY);

// Determine the length of how far we're shooting
int offRealX = realX + projectile.position.x;
int offRealY = realY + projectile.position.y;
float length = sqrtf((offRealX*offRealX)+(offRealY*offRealY));
float velocity = 480/1; // 480pixels/1sec
float realMoveDuration = length/velocity;

// Move projectile to actual endpoint
[projectile runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                       [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:realMoveDuration position:realDest],
                       [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)],
                       nil]];
//add to the projectiles array
projectile.tag = 2;
[_projectiles addObject:projectile];
```

}*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I have completed paper toss using cocos2d.I implemented bezier curve and here it is,

```
  // Bezier curve control points
  bezier.controlPoint_1 = ccp(location.x-CONTROL_POINT1_X, CONTROL_POINT1_Y);
  bezier.controlPoint_2 = ccp(location.x-CONTROL_POINT2_X, CONTROL_POINT2_Y);
  bezier.endPosition = ccp(location.x-CONTROL_POINT1_X,distance);

  // Motion along bezier curve and finally call a function
  [projectile runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                           [CCAutoBezier actionWithDuration:DEFAULT_ACTION_DURATION bezier:bezier],
                           [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(collisionCheck:)], nil]];
```

Comment: I have added a fan in 3 levels and now my game luks great :)

Comment: Can you please tell me more about the CONTROL_POINT

Comment: @TonyMac :- We can use Bezier curve for projectile kind of motion. But  in paper toss i had seen the size of paper also varies. How u do that ? also can u please tell me how can we implement the bounce effect when paper collides the edges of dustbin ? thanks

Comment: can u please explain about CONTROL_POINT ?

Answer (score 2):

Just scale your sprite image so it gets smaller the "further away" it is.

Comment: What do you mean by the "exact perspective view"?

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can use `bezier curve` for `3d` perspective view in `cocos2d`.

```
bezier.controlPoint_1 = ccp(location.x-CONTROL_POINT1_X, CONTROL_POINT1_Y);
  bezier.controlPoint_2 = ccp(location.x-CONTROL_POINT2_X, CONTROL_POINT2_Y);
```