# Box2D collision implementation point, movement along the z-axis

Tags: box2d, collision, bezier, curve

I have a question regarding realistic looking object flight in 2D - via the best placement of control points using Bezier.

I'm in the middle of developing a Paper Toss-like game - in java. I am aware that Cocos2D can provide me with the set Bezier function, but I preferred to experiment with writing out the math involved for creating the curve.

The Bezier curve is cubic (4 control points) and travels along the z-axis. For those wanting more information on the Bezier path movement, there are heaps of articles available like here: http://www.create-games.com/article.asp?id=1866

My question is: to replicate the Paper Toss feel, I can't figure out whether I should be looking to place my endpoint at the top of the basket. 
Or place my curve endpoint on the floor - and use Box2D's collision functionality to detect the basket along the projectiles movement path.

In the difficult mode in Paper Toss, it appears that the p3 point (endpoint) is off the floor and then used a pre-drawn animation for the fall to the floor. I imagine this is the same technique they have used to for when the object hits the rim of the basket and does one of the same four 'bounce' animations. Perhaps...

So this question is for those that think they can replicate the look of the flight - as opposed to the specifics in code, which I believe shouldn't be an issue for me at this point. I've been researching this idea for a while, but resorted to asking the question. So you may well be helping many more programmers in the future if you can crack this.

Comment: You know about parabolas and perspective projection, right? what's this cubic bezier business?

Comment: I was anticipating responses that would direct me to cocos2d and the bezier function to replicate the perspective projection you're talking about. Every related post i've seen to paper toss clones have been built in cocos2d. The other reason beziers come up is because if you log flick speed, you can change the arc of the curve with the control points. Paper Toss apparently do this.              But if i take the bezier stuff out, do you have an idea on whether I should be drawing my curve to the top of the basket rim, or the floor?

Comment: I don't know what kind of game you're trying to create. I can however tell you that I personally cannot understand why the Paper Toss game is suitable to emulate. It does an absolutely **abysmal** job of simulating the mechanics (gravity, rendering the size of the projectile, computing the trajectory of the projectile, colliding the projectile against its target, I could go on). Perhaps its appeal lies in the forgiving way that you'll land it in the can if your swipe is anywhere near at the right angle. It's really not more than a one-dimensional aiming game with a few mundane animations.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Gun.. I haven't played enough PT to really have thought about the trajectory mechanics. But in this stack post - [3D perspective view in iphone game using cocos2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871732/3d-perspective-view-in-iphone-game-using-cocos2d/9990419#9990419)

you'll find someone who what supposedly been able to recreate the game. They have marked the their endpoint x coordinate as being the same as control point 1s x coordinate. I expect to you will need to place your floor object correctly to stop the paper flying back in the wrong direction.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this so quick. I have actually seen this post before. I'm not convinced it's correct. Thought I do see what they are doing - by having the end point set before the floor level. My experimentation so far makes me think the curve that would result from this won't look accurate enough though. I think this person may have just looked for an endpoint to pin to - that looked 'about' right. Thanks though